# How often does PubsubIO.readStrings pull from subscription

Tags: google-cloud-dataflow, apache-beam, google-cloud-pubsub

I'm trying to understand Beam/Dataflow concepts better, so pretend I have the following streaming pipeline:

```java
pipeline
    .apply(PubsubIO.readStrings().fromSubscription("some-subscription"))
    .apply(ParDo.of(new DoFn<String, String>() {
      @ProcessElement
      public void processElement(ProcessContext c) {
        String message = c.element();

        LOGGER.debug("Got message: {}", message);

        c.output(message);
      }
}));
```

1. How often will the unbounded source pull messages from the subscription? Is this configurable at all (potentially based on windows/triggers)?
2. Since no custom windowing/triggers have been defined, and there are no sinks (just a ParDo that logs + re-outputs the message), will my ParDo still be executed immediately as messages are received, and is that setup problematic in any way (not having any windows/triggers/sinks defined)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It will pull messages from the subscription continuously - as soon as a message arrives, it will be processed immediately (modulo network and RPC latency).

Windowing and triggers do not affect this at all - they only affect how the data gets grouped at grouping operations (GroupByKey and Combine). If your pipeline doesn't have grouping operations, windowing and triggers are basically a no-op.

The Beam model does not have the concept of a sink - writing to various storage systems (e.g. writing files, writing to BigQuery etc) is implemented as regular Beam composite transforms, made of `ParDo` and `GroupByKey` like anything else. E.g. writing each element to its own file could be implemented by a `ParDo` whose `@ProcessElement` opens the file, writes the element to it and closes the file.

Comment: Maybe I misunderstood your answer, but the [beam overview](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/programming-guide/#overview) literally talks about sinks -- or is that a different concept? Also, with the example pipeline above, when would the Pub/Sub messages be acknowledged as soon as it passes the ParDo that's simply logging + re-outputing the message?

Comment: Ouch, that part of the documentation is significantly out of date. Beam used to provide an API called Sink a long time ago, but the API was deleted because it became clear that it doesn't do anything that simple composite transforms can't do. We'll update it. As for acknowledgement: it's unspecified when exactly a message is acknowledged. A runner will acknowledge it once the runner can guarantee it won't be lost - e.g. if the runner has durably persisted it in a buffer, or if it has been processed and the results of that have been durably persisted, etc.

Comment: I've sent a pull request to fix the documentation https://github.com/apache/beam-site/pull/386

Comment: And regd when the messages are acked : yes, messages are acked after they pass through your ParDo. Dataflow runner makes a small bundles of messages and runs your ParDo on them, once the bundle is done, all of the messages in the bundle are acked. Bundle size could be really small (single message) or some what larger in case of high volume PubSub topics.

Comment: Thanks @jkff + @raghu-angadi!